# How to replace comma inside .data javascript function (with .replace)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, replace, str-replace

When sorting a list of divs I am trying to replace the comma from the extracted values (using .data).

The values with a comma won't sort properly. How can I use the replace functions to sort the divs correctly?

```
 <script>   
    $(".button").click(function(){
         var divList = $(".cell");
         divList.sort(function(b, a){
         return $(a).data("number")-$(b).data("number")
         });
    $(".table").html(divList);
    });
</script>

<div class="button">Click</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell" data-number="1,942"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="42"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="161"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="5,382"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="892"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="4"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="38"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
<script>    
    $("button").click(function(){
        var divList = $(".cell");
        divList.sort(function(b, a){
        return $(a).data("number").replace(/,/g, '')-$(b).data("number").replace(/,/g, '')
    });
    $(".table").html(divList);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use `parseInt`. i.e. `parseInt($(a).data("number").replace(/,/g, '')) - parseInt($(b).data("number").replace(/,/g, ''))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `toString()` and then `replace()` function like following. BTW in the first line of your html may be your using `div` instead of `button`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell" data-number="1,942">1,942</div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="42">42</div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="161">161</div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="5,382">5,382</div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="892">892</div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="4">4</div>
    <div class="cell" data-number="38">38</div>
</div>

<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
        var divList = $(".cell");
        divList.sort(function (b, a) {
            return $(a).data("number").toString().replace(/,/g, '') - $(b).data("number").toString().replace(/,/g, '');
        });
        $(".table").html(divList);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$(".button").click(function() { // You missed the . for class here
  $(".cell").each(function() { // Loop through each cell
    // Set the data-number attribute
    $(this).attr('data-number', $(this).attr('data-number').replace(',', ''));
  });
});
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/07fgmLd4/)